# use IF ISNUMBER SEARCH to exclude data

Tags: excel

I'm having a hard time trying to get excel to get the information I want.  Here is the short of it:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("individual",F2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("multiple",J2))),BJ2,"")
```

The formula above is written to display whatever is in cell BJ2 if all the conditions are met.  I'm trying to tweak this formula so it displays what is in BJ2 if individual is in F2 and multiple is not in J2.  Is this possible in excel?

Comment: Change the second `ISNUMBER` to `ISERROR`

Comment: Thanks.  That was so simple.  I appreciate the second set of eyes on this.